# Iphone text file reading

Tags: iphone, file, ios4, text, file-io

I'm trying to read data from 1.txt in my iphone project's resources folder using the following code:

```
NSString *fileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", currentLevel] stringByAppendingString:@".txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; 
NSAssert(fileContent!=nil, @"file's contents are nil");
```

currentLevel is an integer which is initially set to 1. It doesn't matter whether I replace [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", currentLevel] stringByAppendingString:@".txt"] with @"1.txt" (for testing the first level) because both times NSAssert fails

why isn't this working? I've imported 1.txt to xcode and it's in the resources file. it's not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", currentLevel] ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:file encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```